# DialogViewController not showing navigationbar

Tags: ios, mvvmcross

I am instantiating a DialogViewController within a MvvmCross View like this

```
var myDialog = new MyDialogViewController();
var navController = new UINavigationController();
controller.NavigationBar.TintColor = UIColor.Black;
controller.PushViewController(myDialog, false);
Add(controller.View);
```

And this is how the MyDialogViewController looks like:

```
public class MyDialogViewController : DialogViewController
{
    public MyDialogViewController()
        : base(UITableViewStyle.Grouped, new RootElement("MyRoot"), true)
    {
        var root = new RootElement("MyRoot") {
             new Section 
             {
                new HtmlElement("MyWebsite", https://www.mywebsite.com")
             }              
        };
        Root.Add(root);
    }
}
```

The dialog appears fine with the NavigationBar but if I select the Html element MyWebsite the Webview is displayed but without the NavigationBar and I am not able to navigate back.

The same thing occurs for elements that require to navigate to a new window, the navigationbar is not shown.

Any idea how to make the NavigationBar show after navigating to the WebView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
var settings = new SettingsDialogViewController((SettingsViewModel)ViewModel, new RootElement("Settings"));
var window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
navigationController = window.RootViewController.ChildViewControllers[1].NavigationController;
navigationController.PushViewController(settings, true);
navigationController.NavigationBarHidden = false;
```